# How do I use the options pattern to configure properties for HttpClient?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, configuration

I've been reading up on the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) prescribed by Microsoft to allow strongly-typed configuration to be [registered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#use-di-services-to-configure-options) at application startup, which can later be injected into services that need access to the configured values.

My application uses HttpClient to issue HTTP requests, and naturally, I want to store the target URIs in configuration as they will change per environment (dev/test/etc).

I have heard that even though HttpClient implements IDisposable, we should not wrap it in a using (... statement because it can leak connections while it's waiting for the connection to time out after disposal. This leads to an implementation involving a [static property](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/#:%7E:text=private%20static%20HttpClient%20Client%20%3D%20new%20HttpClient()%3B) that holds the instance of HttpClient for the lifetime of the application, to avoid that leak.

So now I'm stuck with figuring out how to instantiate a static, hopefully readonly, property that depends on configuration I'm going to receive in the instance constructor. Sounds like I'll need a lock or something, but I'm not sure the safest way to structure that.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has [introduced IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to resolve this issue.

> To address the issues mentioned above and to make HttpClient instances
> manageable, .NET Core 2.1 introduced the IHttpClientFactory interface
> which can be used to configure and create HttpClient instances in an
> app through Dependency Injection (DI).

I have this setup working in my Azure Functions App by calling `.AddHttpClient` instead of `.AddTransient` when wiring up my services. This forwards to `IHttpClientFactory` under the covers, remediating the issues with `new`ing up `HttpClient` directly.